# J-session id is changed when navigated from one https page to other https page on tomcat 6.0.24

Tags: security, tomcat, https, session-cookies, jsessionid

our product customers are trying to have direct login to one of our secured pages.

```
login url="https://" + anIp + ":5443/om";

GetMethod authget = new GetMethod(url);
..
Header cookie = authget.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
```

the cookie(J-session id)for the login page is saved in cookie and this is again used in the second get to access some info from the second page that comes after login page.

second page `url=https://" + anIp + ":5443/om/service.do?action=listservice`

note : both pages are secured ones(https).
The problem is: on tomcat5.5 we observed that the both the cookies are same.
but on tomcat 6.0 when we try to access the second page using the first cookie it is not working.we observed that even though navigation is from https page to another https(only) page the cookie got changed on 6.0.
I am not able to figure out what is wrong in 6.0.
Is there any change in the cookie management from 5.5 to 6.0 tomcat.
Please let me know if anyone knows about this.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Tomcat change session ids when you cross an authentication boundary (e.g. you enter a username and password). This is to prevent session fixation attacks.

If you have a client that is tracking the session id, then you need to continuously track the session id, updating your session id for every response that includes a JSESSIONID cookie.